# Best way to create a Date Object with this string in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving this date/time from an API:

`2012-03-31 12:00:00`

What is the best way to do this:

`var date = new Date("2012-03-31 12:00:00")` without Firefox complaining of an Invalid Date?

Comment: Use a library like http://momentjs.com/ ?

Comment: @FelixKling Really?? Is the use of a library needed to do this?

Comment: No it's not needed, you can also parse the string yourself and extract the fields and pass them to `Date`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, so at the moment, I'm doing: val = val.replace(/-/ig, ','); just seems a little hacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match all the fields in the date time string with:

```
var str = "2012-03-31 12:00:00";
var fields = str.match(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/);
```

Now `fields[1]` contains the year, `fields[2]` the month, etc. Then you can call `Date` with:

```
// months are zero-based, so we have to subtract 1
var date = new Date(+fields[1], +fields[2] - 1, +fields[3], +fields[4], +fields[5], +fields[6]);
```

---

Or use a library like http://momentjs.com/ which does this for you.

Comment: Nice answer, if your date string has in a different format just modify the regex groups and works.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the date you could use:

```
var date = new Date("2012-03-31 12:00:00".split(" ")[0]);
```

& firefox wont complain.